# Is it possible to use Bootstrap in conjunction with the standard Salesforce styles?

Tags: visualforce, css, bootstrap, stylesheets

Is it possible to use Bootstrap in a VFP without having to use `standardStylesheets="false"` and `showHeader="false"`?

When I solely add in the stylesheets tag, my whole page is altered a little bit. The font is much larger but that is the only change. Even if I put in a `styleClass="btn btn-primary` on a button, I get no response from Bootstrap. That is until I add in the two tags, standardStylesheet=false and showHeader=false. I also am unable to override the standard style with inline style editing or style tags in the header.

So is it possible to use Bootstrap in conjunction with the standard Salesforce styles? Without having to overwrite the page with an iFrame?

Code examples:

```
<apex:page id="ACHBounce" standardController="Case" extensions="ACHBounceController">
   <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/37.0/integration.js"/>
   <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
   <apex:stylesheet value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
   <apex:stylesheet value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<apex:commandButton value="Start1" style="background-color:red;" styleClass="btn btn-primary" action="{!test}"/>
<apex:commandLink action="{!test}" value="Start2" id="ACHButton" styleClass="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start3" onclick="test(); return false;"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="test()" type="button">Start4</button>
```

Comment: If you use scoped BS CSS then I believe so.

Comment: You might consider [VisualStrap](https://github.com/Avinava/VisualStrap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the CSS goes all over the place is that Salesforce uses the same class names and properties as Bootstrap. If there's a conflict, Salesforce wins. There's two reasons I can think of that this would happen, either Salesforce is using `!important` after each property, or Salesforce renders their stylesheets after everything else and because CSS literally cascades, the last properties rendered are used, any before it are ignored. The latter is most likely.

One way to do this would be to use namespacing within the CSS itself. This means you wouldn't be able to call Bootstrap from a CDN, rather you'd need to reference it as a static resource.

The best way is to namespace your bootstrap classes and styles, which basically means adding `.bootstrap` before each declaration block. You *could* do this manually which can be time consuming, or you could use a tool like [CSS Prefix](http://www.css-prefix.com/).

Assuming you've namespaced each declation with `.bootstrap`, you could then just code something as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlock styleClass="bootstrap">
  <!-- Other Markup with Bootstrap classes -->
</pageBlock>
```

This means Bootstrap's styles only get applied to elements inside the `<apex:pageBlock/>` with a class of "Bootstrap" and won't affect other Salesforce stuff, such as the header or sidebar.

Comment: awesome suggestion. I got it up in running in less then 10 minutes! Thank you!

Comment: @Olivia Good to know. It may be worth looking at VisualStrap as Adrian suggested, although sadly it hasn't been updated in almost a year.